# Using abstract, derived, virtual or interface in an asp.net SOAP servive

Tags: asp.net, soap

I wonder whether there's any approach to use abstract classes (resp. it's derived children) in an asp.net SOAP webservice?..

Idea is the following: I have a SOAP service that requires as input one Departure object and one destination Destination object. But both Departure and Destination are actually one of the following objects: DepartureCity, DepartureRegion, DepartureCountry, ... (derived from generic parent class DepartureDestination)

Q: Is it possible to use derived objects in a SOAP service (without seriously hacking into the .NET framework)? Maybe by using abstact, virtual, interface or "regular" derived child objects?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: When using abstract for the base class, the child classes are not serialized in the WSDL, in WSDL I only see the parent DepartureDestination object. I also tried interface but here XmlSerialization failed: Cannot serialize member XYZ because it is an interface.

Comment: Yeah see KnownType attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KnownType is for WCF only, not for SOAP. But I figured out how it works, in case someone else is looking for the solution: I just needed to add the XmlInclude for the child classes and - surprise - the derived child classes also appear in the WSDL:

```
public class Airport : Location
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Code;
}

public class City : Location
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Code;
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(Airport))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(City))]
public abstract class Location
{
    public LocationType Type
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.GetType().Name == typeof(Airport).Name)
            {
                return LocationType.Airport;
            }
            else if (this.GetType().Name == typeof(City).Name)
            {
                return LocationType.City;
            }
            else throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown LocationType");
        }
    }
}
```